# Add fixed tag to diigo bookmarklet - javascript

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a simple change to a standard diigo bookmarklet. I wish to add a fixed tag to the Diigo 'Add New Bookmark' form. My code is:

```
javascript:javascript:(function(){
var url=location.href;
var title=document.title||url;
var tagsvar='TestTag';
var desc=(window.getSelection?window.getSelection().toString():document.getSelection?
document.getSelection():document.selection.createRange().text);
window.open('https://www.diigo.com/post?
url='+encodeURIComponent(url)+'
&title='+encodeURIComponent(title)+'
&desc='+encodeURIComponent(desc)+'
&tags='+tagsvar+'&client=simplelet#main','_blank','menubar=no,height=580,width=608,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,status=no');
})();
```

All I have added is:

```
var tagsvar='TestTag';
```

and

```
&tags='+tagsvar+'
```

Url, title and desc are correctly entered into the Diigo form but the tags field is blank.

I am new to javascript so probably a basic error.
Thank you for your help

Comment: did you read the documentation about the format of `tags` ? did you try `encodeURIComponent(tagsvar)` ?

Comment: Thankyou Shivan. I have tried                      encodeURIComponent(tagsvar) with same outcome. I cannot find any specific tags formatting requirements